# View all queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, benchmarking, sql-server-2008-express

I got a MVC3 application using Entity Framework 4 and SQL Server.

How can I view all queries that has been invoked (and the amount of time that they took)?

Comment: I think best way is to use SQL Server Profiler from SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the sql profiler, it will give you all this information and more. Won't require any code changes either.

Heres a link to a free one if you don't have the full toolset.

http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler

Comment: But the question is tagged with SQL Server Express tag = no SQL profiler.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/, also he may have the full toolset but only have sqlexpress deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot without [additional tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx). Simply EF doesn't have such feature. The referenced article describes some tools (SQL profiler, DotTrace, EF Provider Wrappers, EFProf, Huagati profiler) but there are also:

- [MVC mini profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/)
- [ORM profiler](http://www.ormprofiler.com/defaultgeneric.aspx)

Not every tool is free but those which are not have a trial version.